# Encontrar en string y devolver dependiendo condición

Tags: php

Estoy intentando hacer una función en PHP el cual recibe una cadena (nombre de una dependencia) y dependiendo del nombre le otorga un "género" (el/la), como se muestra a continuación:

```
$depe =ucwords($_POST['depe']);
function gen_depe($var){
// $var = substr($var, 0, 100);
$facu = 'FACULTAD';
$esc = 'ESCUELA';
$coord = 'COORDINACION';
$centro = 'CENTRO';
$inst= 'INSTITUTO';
if( (strpos($var,$facu) === false) OR (strpos($var,$esc)===false) OR (strpos($var,$coord)===false) ){
    return "La $var ";
}elseif( (strpos($var,$centro) === false) OR (strpos($var,$inst)===false) ){
    return "el $var";
}else{
    echo "Algo está mal";
}
}

echo gen_depe($depe);
```

el problema surge que siempre me devuelve la opción de "la" sin importar que se coloque CENTRO O INSTITUCIÓN, y no logro dar con la solución, les agradecería mucho su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: El tema es que `strpos` devuelve `false` cuando falla, entonce siempre va a entrar en el primer `if` porque alguna de esas condiciones siempre va a fallar. Tenes que usar `0` (_cero_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que la función [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php) devuelve una posición (`int`) o `false` si no fue encontrada la cadena que busca. Osea, la comparación con `false` solo deberías hacerlo para saber si la cadena que estás buscando no existe en tu variable `$var`.

Para que te funcione en tu código deberías agregar el símbolo "**!**" antes del paréntesis.

```php
if( !(strpos($var,$facu) === false) OR !(strpos($var,$esc)===false) OR !(strpos($var,$coord)===false) ){
    return "La $var ";
}elseif( !(strpos($var,$centro) === false) OR !(strpos($var,$inst)===false) ){
    return "el $var";
}else{
    return "Algo está mal";
}
```

También estás convirtiendo en minúsculas la cadena de texto que estás recibiendo con la función [ucwords](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ucwords).

```php
$depe =ucwords($_POST['depe']);
```

El valor de tus variables también deberían estar en minúsculas:

```php
$facu = 'facultad';
$esc = 'escuela';
$coord = 'coordinacion';
$centro = 'centro';
$inst= 'instituto';
```

Una alternativa a tu código es usar dos arrays. En uno tendrías los elementos que pertenecen al género femenino y en el otro al género masculino. Y para saber en qué género corresponde usarías la función [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array).

```php
$depe = ucwords($_POST['depe']);

function gen_depe($var) {
    $generoFemenino = array(
        'facultad',
        'escuela',
        'coordinacion'
    );
    $generoMasculino = array(
        'centro',
        'instituto'
    );

    if( in_array($var, $generoFemenino) ) {
        return "La $var";
    } else if( in_array($var, $generoMasculino) ) {
        return "El $var";
    } else {
        return "Algo está mal";
    }
}

echo gen_depe($depe);
```

Answer (score 1):

yo utilizaría esta formula para resolver

```php
function gen_depe($var){
   $fem=array('0','FACULTAD','ESCUELA','COORDINACION');
   $mas=array('0','CENTRO','INSTITUTO'); 
   if(!array_search($var,$fem)==false){
      return "La $var ";
   }elseif(!array_search($var,$mas)==false){
      return "el $var";
   }else{
      echo "Algo está mal";
   }
   echo"<br>";
}
    
$depe='CENTRO';
echo gen_depe($depe);
$depe='FACULTAD';
echo gen_depe($depe);
```

como nota adicional agrego un elemento en la posición 0 debido a que [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php) retorna la posición o false y el if toma 0 y false como false.

Comment: te recomiendo agregar el link de la docunmentacion oficial de php cuando espliques o implemente metodos nativos como array_search

Answer (score 0):

Tomando en cuenta que los valores evaluados tendrian que ser elegidos de alguna lista, podria resolver el problema de la siguiente manera:

```
function obtenerGenero($strDependencia) {
  if (strtoupper(substr($strDependencia, -1)) == 'O')
    return "EL {$strDependencia}";
  else
    return "LA {$strDependencia}";
}
echo obtenerGenero('CENTRO');
echo obtenerGenero('ESCUELA');
```

Y si la cadena ingresada es un texto abierto, sugiero reconsiderar esa caracteristica, puesto que el error retornado no tendria sentido si no se le sugiere al usuario los valores permitidos.